# Colon is Missing In My Website Url in Wordpress Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, site-url, http

So I've had this shortcode [site_url] working fine until a few days ago, now as I'm trying to use it again and it shows me a `https//` instead of `https://`.

I've tried using this function:

```
//Website URL shortcode [site_url]
add_action( 'init', function() {
add_shortcode( 'site_url', function( $atts = null, $content = null ) {
    return site_url();
    } );
} );
```

And I've also tried this one:

```
    function create_site_url()
{
    return home_url();
}

add_shortcode('site_url', 'create_site_url');
```

I've also tried to check my wp_options table and they are all correct and all have the ":"

I'm currently at a loss to why it stopped working, as I've installed no new plugins and made 0 changes. All the older shortcode applications seem to be calling the `https://`, however any new applications of the same shortcode just pull `http//`

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: nothing in the code you've shared would cause this, the problem lays elsewhere. Disable all plugins and turn them back on one by one until the problem returns to find the culprit. Also check your site URL is set correctly

Comment: Ok, I just got a new piece of info: aparently it's only when I'm creating a url with the shortcode. If I use just the shortcode in normal text it just shows up with ```https://´´´

Comment: What do you mean by “ when I'm creating a url”?